# Decorator Pattern: How to create the final object based on just user input?

Tags: design-patterns

I started learning the decorator pattern and it is the first time that i am faced with this kind of problem.

What bothers me is this line:

```
Drink drinkObject = new ChocolateDecorator(new SoyDecorator(new Espresso()));
```

Let's say i make a simple interface for the user to select the ingredients. How can i declare the object at runtime based on user input only?

Example: the user selects two "Soy" then the object should be:

```
Drink drinkObject = new SoyDecorator(new SoyDecorator(new Espresso()));
```

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Drink drinkObject = new ChocolateDecorator(new SoyDecorator(new Espresso())); 
        System.out.println("Order: "+ drinkObject.nameDescription());
        System.out.println("Total Price: " + drinkObject.price());
    }

}


abstract class Drink{
    public abstract String nameDescription();
    public abstract double price();
}

class Espresso extends Drink {

    public String nameDescription() {
        return "Expresso" + " with:";
    }
    public double price() {
        return 1;
    }
}

abstract class DrinkDecorator extends Drink {

    protected Drink drink;
    public DrinkDecorator(Drink drinkObject) {
        this.drink = drinkObject;
    }

    public abstract String nameDescription();
    public abstract double price();
}

class ChocolateDecorator extends DrinkDecorator{

    public ChocolateDecorator(Drink drinkObject) {
        super(drinkObject);
    }

    public String nameDescription() {
        return this.drink.nameDescription()+ " Chocolate;";
    }
    public double price() {
        return this.drink.price() + 0.25;
    }
}

class SoyDecorator extends DrinkDecorator{

    public SoyDecorator(Drink drinkObject) {
        super(drinkObject);
    }

    public String nameDescription() {
        return this.drink.nameDescription()+ " Soy;";
    }
    public double price() {
        return this.drink.price() + 0.15;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for possibly poor Java code: the language is not my strong point.

The idea, I believe, is to iterate over the input and choosing which decorator to apply at each iteration. Something like

```
Drink drinkObject = new Espresso();
for (String kind: args) {
    switch (kind) {
        case "soy":       drinkObject = new SoyDecorator(drinkObject);
                          break;
        case "chocolate": drinkObject = new ChocolateDecorator(drinkObject);
                          break; 
        default:          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: aha! nice idea. quite obvious now that i see it. thanks a lot dude, really appreciate it!